# OpenSearch script - accessing global variables inside a function

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless, opensearch

I'm writing some sorting scripts for OpenSearch (fork of ElasticSearch). The script environment defines some global constants, like `doc`, that are available at the top level of the script, but apparently not inside a function definition.

```
def getPrice() {
    return doc["price"];  // compile error: cannot resolve symbol [doc]
}

int price = doc["price"]; // this works
```

Can someone point me to the documentation which explains precisely where and when the globals are available? And is there any way to access `doc` inside a function, like adding a namespace prefix or something? (Obviously, I could pass it in as a function parameter, but I just want to see if that's really necessary.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opensearch scripts are based on [Painless](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-painless.html) as well.

Painless functions are not well documented, but they have been designed to be [completely independent](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/36993#issuecomment-452351374) of the script body, so anything that the function should work on must be passed as parameters.

```
def getPrice(Map document) {
    return document["price"];    
}

int price = getPrice(doc);
```